# Find the area on the surface of the parabolic cylinder $z=4-y^2$ on the first octant between the planes $y=x$ and $y=2x$ below $z=3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

The title is the statement of the problem. I want to calculate that area with a double integral.

I started the exercise replacing $z=3$ on $z=4-y^2$ and so I got $y=1$ and $y=-1$ so $0≤y≤1$ and $ \dfrac{1}{2}≤x≤1$. And I don't know what to do with $z$. Would these be the limits of my integral? How do I now build the integral to get the area that the exercise asks for?

All the help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$In the first octant and below $z = 3$ means $0 < z < 3$. Plugin the surface $z = 4 - y^2$ we have

$$0 < 4 - y^2 < 3 \implies 1 < y < 2$$

Between $y = x$ and $y = 2x$ gives the interval $\frac{y}2 < x < y$. One can easily make a sketch and see that the region of integration is a trapezoid.

Anyway, even without the visual aid, we have algebraically $$\int_{y = 1}^2\int_{x=y/2}^y \sqrt{1 + \Bigl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr)^2}\dd{y} \dd{x}$$
with $f(x,y) = z(x,y) = 4-y^2$ .

That's the setting-up. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can! Thank you!!